# Is there any Robot Framework library to automate testing of JavaFX GUIs embeded in Swing

Tags: swing, javafx, automation, robotframework

I have an application that has Swing component that are embedding JavaFx Browser in it.

For Swing Automation I am using Robot Framework's Swing Library.

But Swing Library is not able to identify JavaFx Browser. Is there any library which I can integrate with Swing Library to Automate Java Fx Component.